# How to make a left-side bar chart on kendoui?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, bar-chart, right-to-left

Using KendoUi, I'd like to create a bar chart where the bars will deploy from the right to the left (with the vertical axis on the right side of the chart).

More prcisely I'd like to make a chart with a central axis and bars on each side, like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uspop.svg

But I'll be able to join the two charts if I have a left-side bar chart and a regular (right-sided) one...

Comment: can you post your script for charting

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try to set **reverse: true** to the **valueAxis** of the Kendo UI Chart? For example: http://jsbin.com/apolob/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

**freddy**, I searched through the docs for kendo ui chart and could not find any option to change the position of axis instead i will suggest you a custom javascript jquery solution. you can mirror the div containing chart.
here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VmFK9/) for that so that you can have an idea

this is just a suggestion but i hope it does not hurt and may help

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But if any body has a solution (even by modifying some kendoui functions) to find this out with kendoui, it would be helpfull... (and sorry, I can't vote up for this post, I'm new here)

Comment: it's ok buddy rather i would be glad if this piece of code helps you in anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've tried an other thing : while using stacked bars, I made a positive bar and a negative one : as stacked, they're on the same line so it's ok for what I want.
But on the left side of the chart, values are printed negatives (because they are !!). Isn't it possible to print them all positive (like with an absolute value) ?
I've tried to change the "format" in valueAxis but impossible to find this out.
Thanks for your ideas or solutions !!